# How can I pass data from $.post request to a file and print

Tags: javascript, php

in my code I use a $.post request and I get some data back. I want these data printed (on paper!). My code in javascript is:

```
$('#printDamages').click(function(){
                var printDmgs = [];
                $.each($("input[name='chk_group']:checked"), function(){            
                    printDmgs.push($(this).val());
                });
                $.post('ajax_Print_Damages.php',
                    {
                        inner     :   JSON.stringify(printDmgs)
                    },
                    function(data){
                        window.print();  //I tried this but ofcourse is printing current window
                    }        
                );
            });
```

Has anyone something to suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function(data){
    var newWindow = window.open('','','width=200,height=200');
    newWindow.document.write(data);
    newWindow.print();
}
```